# How to keep track of time in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, timestamp

I have a game that shoots bad guys from the right at the player who is on the left.

I want the spawn rate of my enemies to get faster as the time of game play increases.

I have set a double `timeOfStart = CACurrentMediaTime();` in my init & a`NSLog(@"time is %d", timeOfStart + dt);` in the update method.

But I get values like:

```
time is 1581741008
time is 863073232
time is -1024003120
time is -1390701616
time is 14971856
```

Why do i get big values, then smaller, then negative!?

Comment: scheduleUpdate and keep adding delta time of update method to a totalTime ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CACurrentMediaTime() returns double value.

So

```
NSLog(@"time is %f", timeOfStart + dt);
```

You can track time in Two ways:

1. Use NSTimeInterval

   ```
   //Declare it as member variable in .h file
   NSTimeInterval      mLastSpeedUpdateTime;


   //In .m init method
   mLastSpeedUpdateTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

   //In update method
   NSTimeInterval interval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

   float diff = (interval - mLastSpeedUpdateTime);

   if(  diff > 5.0f ) //5second
   {
        //here update game speed.
        mLastSpeedUpdateTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
   }
   ```
2. Manually track time:

   ```
      //Declare this in .h
      float                mTimeInSec;

   .m init method
   mTimeInSec = 0.0f;

      -(void)tick:(ccTime)dt
       {
            mTimeInSec +=0.1f;

             //update gamespeed for every 10sec or on ur needs
             if(mTimeInSec>=10.0f)
             {
               //update game speed
               mTimeInSec = 0.0f;
             }  
       }
   ```

Comment: `schedule` is not a precise solution since it is related with frame rate. But I think it's still precise enough in @marciokoko 's case.

Comment: @ReckHou, every game has atleast one update thread in cocos2d...!

Comment: So what? `schedule` takes effect once a frame is rendered.

Comment: But sometimes game runs below 60 or 30 FPS caused by a performance bottleneck, so that's why it's not precise.